# unix shell script variable declaration - command not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
nOption=' | awk '{total+=$1} END {print total/1024"kb"}' '
find . -type f -printf "%s %p/n"| sort -nr | head -n10 $nOption
```

I would like to create a script to find the biggest file at current directory.
This is my script, there had a error if I use the variable to substitute....

the output :
./big.sh: line 67: +=: command not found

but it works if i do not use variable :

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p/n"| sort -nr | head -n10 | awk '{total+=$1} END {print total/1024"kb"}'
```

the output is what should i want:
680.021kb

What's wrong of my script??

thank you

Comment: Read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Single quoted strings](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) cannot contain other single quotes, so that `awk` command is interpreted as a shell command instead. [Putting commands in variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is tricky, and in general it's easier, safer and more readable to create a function:

```
nOption() {
    awk '{total+=$1} END {print total/1024"kb"}'
}
find . -type f -printf "%s %p/n"| sort -nr | head -n10 | nOption
```

For this specific case, as @chepner points out, the issue is that you *can't* put command separators such as `|` in a string and then execute that as part of a pipe (without [`eval`, which is evil](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)).

Comment: Right answer, but the real problem, even if quoting were done correctly, is that you can't put shell syntax in a parameter like the OP tried. `noption="| awk '...'"` (with proper quoting and escaping in the `awk` script itself) would still fail, because the `|` would be treated as a literal character and therefore just another argument to `head`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with quotes inside quotes, in variable expansion...
Why don't go with a one-liner? It's a (tiny) bit faster, and sleeker... :-)

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p/n"| sort -nr | head -n10 | awk '{total+=$1} END {print total/1024"kb"}'
```

---

**Update**:
To make the script more flexible, you could do:

```
dir="."
units="1024"
unitsstring="kb"
find "$dir" -type f -printf "%s %p/n"| sort -nr | head -n10 | awk '{total+=$1} END {print total/$units"$unitsstring"}'
```

Comment: thank you. It is because this is a part of my script, I would like to change the nOption at some situation.

Comment: I see. But I think it's not possible to expand a variable ($1) inside a variable ($nOption). Flexibility is not obtained putting a command inside a variable, usually... You should select which parts of your command (string "kb", for example?) could change, in the future, and put *these* inside variables... See my updated answer to see an example... See also l0b0's answer, it's a different approach...